# Issues training XGB model - sparkxgb, sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have tried the following code  which I took from (https://github.com/rstudio/sparkxgb). I just changed the deployment mode: instead of  a `"local"` connection I use a `"yarn"` deployment mode.

```
library(sparkxgb)
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn")
iris_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris)

xgb_model <- xgboost_classifier(
  iris_tbl, 
  Species ~ .,
  num_class = 3,
  num_round = 50, 
  max_depth = 4
)
```

But I got the following error message

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.TrackerConf.<init>(XGBoost.scala:50)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.TrackerConf$.apply(XGBoost.scala:53)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.params.GeneralParams$class.$init$(GeneralParams.scala:156)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier.<init>(XGBoostClassifier.scala:51)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier.<init>(XGBoostClassifier.scala:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:166)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:136)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:61)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.$anonfun$channelRead0$1(handler.scala:58)
    at scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable(Breaks.scala:42)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:39)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 42 more
```

I am new to spark environment, I suppose the problem is about the configuration of my cluster but I am not really sure. Please, what am I doing wrong ?